# Javascript create elements in two places

Tags: javascript

How would I need to write this to have the elements created in two places?

Here is my code.

I have tried using `document.getElementsByName` and `document.getElementsByClassName` and neither of them work.

**HTML**

```
<p style="display:block;" class="coords"></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position, coords)
{
    var places = document.getElementsByClassName(coords);
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++)
    {
        places[i].innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='lat' id='lat' value='" + position.coords.latitude + "'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='lon' id='lon' value='" + position.coords.longitude + "'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use one of those functions and then use a `for` loop.

Comment: use document.querySelectorAll("classname"); and make a console log of it, to make sure it returns an array of nodes bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `getElementsByClassName` you must use a loop to update each of them.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var places = document.getElementsByClassName("coords");
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        places[i].innerHTML="<input type='text' name='lat' id='lat' value='" + position.coords.latitude + "'>" +
                            "<input type='text' name='lon' id='lon' value='" + position.coords.longitude + "'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Barmar, it still does not work. I've updated my code to reflect your answer.

Comment: I changed my function to hard-code the class name. I didn't notice that the function was a callback of the geolocation code, so it doesn't pass the class name argument.

Comment: My bad, thank you for your help. I really need to learn javascript. I have php down but for some reason, javascript still looks alien to me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use

`document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByName`

with no capital letter at the start